# Angular observable value undefined after value changes

Tags: angular, typescript

TypeError: Cannot read property 'ip' of null

provider.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { DeviceInterface } from '../interfaces/Device';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DeviceService {

  private _devices = new BehaviorSubject<DeviceInterface[]>([]);
  private baseUrl = 'api/monitoring';
  private dataStore: { devices: DeviceInterface[] } = { devices: [] };
  readonly devices = this._devices.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  loadAll() {
    this.http.get<DeviceInterface[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/devices`).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataStore.devices = data;
        this._devices.next((<any>Object).assign({}, this.dataStore).devices);
      },
      error => console.log('Could not load todos.')
    );
  }

  create(device: DeviceInterface) {
    this.http
      .post<DeviceInterface>(`${this.baseUrl}/add`, device)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.dataStore.devices.push(data);
          this._devices.next((<any>Object).assign({}, this.dataStore).devices);
        },
        error => console.log('Could not create todo.')
      );
  }


}
```

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogService, Dialog } from '../providers/dialog.provider';
import { fadeInOut } from '../app.component.animation';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component'
import {
  LanguageService,
} from '../providers/language.provider';

import { DeviceService } from '../providers/device.provider';
import { DeviceInterface } from '../interfaces/Device';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({

  selector: 'app-monitoring',
  templateUrl: './monitoring.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./monitoring.component.scss'],
  animations: [fadeInOut],
})

export class AppMonitoring implements OnInit {

  dialog: Dialog;
  ShowDevices: boolean;
  devices: Observable<DeviceInterface[]>;

  constructor(
    public language_service: LanguageService,
    public  device_service: DeviceService,
    private dialog_service: DialogService,
    app: AppComponent
  ) {

    app.done$.pipe().subscribe(result => {
      this.ShowDevices = true;
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.devices = this.device_service.devices;
    this.device_service.loadAll();
    this.ShowDevices = false;
    this.dialog_service.DialogState.subscribe(dialog => this.dialog = dialog);
  }

  AddDevice() {
    this.dialog = Dialog.DIALOG_ADD;
    this.dialog_service.ChangeDialog(this.dialog);
  }

  Scan() {
    this.dialog = Dialog.DIALOG_SCAN;
    this.dialog_service.ChangeDialog(this.dialog);
  }

}
```

The html template

```
  <div [@fadeInOut] *ngIf="ShowDevices">

    <div class="box-header" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
      <div class="div-right" style="line-height: 35px;">

        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" (click)="AddDevice()" class="pull-right"><i matTooltipPosition="below" class="fa fa-plus"></i> </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" (click)="Scan()" class="pull-right"><i matTooltipPosition="below" class="fa fa-search"></i> </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <app-device class="flexItemSensor" *ngFor="let device of devices | async; index as i;" [ip]="device?.ip" [name]="device?.name"> </app-device>
  </div>
```

When i add you using

```
this.device_service.create(post);
```

The new item has been added without the input values receiving the following error and the application freezes.

The create function itself is called in a 3rd component with the following code

```
  AddDevice() {

    let post: DeviceInterface = {
      ip: this.AddDeviceForm.value.ip,
      name: this.AddDeviceForm.value.name,
    }
    this.device_service.create(post);

  }
```

> Cannot read property 'ip' of null

I know the item is being stored in the database successfully, when i restart the program i can see the new item with his values, what is the proper way an item to be added with his value shown ?

Best regards!

Edit: I have tried adding the following code in ngOnInit() and on devices being added the new values of devices are indeed null

```
 ngOnInit() {

     this.device_service.devices.subscribe(devices => {
      console.log(devices);
    } ); 
    }
```

Edit 2 : Issue is resolved, turn out that in the back end controller should return the following :

```
        return Ok(device);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <app-device *ngFor="let device of devices | async; index as i;"  [ip]="device?.ip" [name]="device?.name"> </app-device>
```

Comment: The error is gone, however the item has being added to the array but the values are not displayed, in order to see the values the application must be restarted

Comment: Using OnPush? If yes try removing it.

Comment: Can you explain in more details please ? Removing the line "   this.dataStore.devices.push(data); " the new item is not being shown at all

Comment: I an asking about Changedetectionstrategy?

Comment: Can you suggest any other way ?

Comment: Try subscribing your devices in component as see what value you are receiving in console?

Comment: I have updated my question adding subscribe and console.log and the new items added indeed have null values, i suspect the issue is somewhere in    this._devices.next((<any>Object).assign({}, this.dataStore).devices);

Comment: what is printing in console?

Comment: try this :- this._devices.next((<any>Object).assign({}, this.dataStore.devices));

Comment: Adding " this._devices.next((<any>Object).assign({}, this.dataStore.devices)); " the following error appears - Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed, and the new device added still has null values

Comment: change it to :- this._devices.next([...this.dataStore.devices]);

Comment: Same as before, the last element is null, for example " 9: null
length: 10 " when i restart the program the 9th element initially read its value from the DB, also i would like to ask what does "..." in front of this do ? Best regards!

Comment: can you print this.datastore before this._devices.next and tell me what its printing?

Comment: {devices: Array(11)}
devices: Array(11)
0: {ip: "192.168.5.34", name: ""}
1: {ip: "192.168.1.220", name: ""}
2: {ip: "192.168.2.1", name: "testme"}
3: {ip: "192.168.5.6", name: "test2"}
4: {ip: "192.168.5.9", name: "test2"}
5: {ip: "192.168.5.10", name: "testme3"}
6: {ip: "192.168.10.10", name: "testme4"}
7: {ip: "192.168.65.98", name: ""}
8: {ip: "192.168.10.50", name: "test5"}
9: {ip: "192.168.5.8", name: "test"}
10: null
length: 11
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
This is the current output

Comment: Thank you for your help issue has been resolved, turned out the back end controller should return Ok(device); Your comments helped me and your proposed checks are useful.Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

The `BehaviorSubject` would immediately emit the current value it holds on subscription. By the time the `async` triggers the subscription the value of the observable is still the default (an empty array `[]`). So there is no `ip` property.

#### Option 1

Use [safe navigation operator `?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) to check if the value is defined before trying to access it's properties

```html
<app-device *ngFor="let device of devices | async; index as i;"  [ip]="device?.ip" [name]="device?.name"> </app-device>
```

#### Option 2

Try to check beforehand if the array is non-empty using `*ngIf` directive.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(devices | async) as devicesData">
  <ng-container *ngIf="devicesData.length > 0">
    <app-device *ngFor="let device of devicesData; index as i;"  [ip]="device.ip" [name]="device.name"> </app-device>
  <ng-container>
<ng-container>
```

Comment: Using option one the error is gone and a new item has been added, but the new values of the array  cannot be seen until the application is restarted

Comment: Probably the change detection isn't kicking-in in the `Device` component. Would it possible to post it's controller and template code?

Comment: Sure i have updated my question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @spstrademark: I meant the Typescript controller and the HTML template of the component corresponding to the `app-device` selector.

Comment: I have updated my question adding the full templates also showing how i call the create function. Best regards!